# Does this metric induce the topology on the product space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ with the discrete topology on it. Moreover, consider $Z=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ with the associated product topology. The cylindersets
$$
[a_n,...,a_m]:=\left\{x\in Z: x_i=a_i, n\leq i\leq m\right\}
$$
are a base of the product topology on $Z$.

I have a rather short question.

Does the metric
$$
d(x,y)=\begin{cases}2, & x\neq y, x_0\neq y_0\\2^{-k}\text{ with k maximal such that }x_{[-k,k]}=y_{[-k,k]}, & x\neq y, x_0=y_0\\0, & x=y\end{cases}
$$
on $Z$ induce the product topology on $Z$?

---

What I already know:

1. The induced topology is the set $\tau$ of all open sets of $(Z,d)$.
2. The cylindersets are open sets of $(Z,d)$.
3. Any union of open sets of $(Z,d)$ is an open set of $(Z,d)$, hence any union of cylindersets is an open set of $(Z,d)$.
4. From 2. and 3. and the fact that the cylinder sets form a base of the product topology on $Z$, I know that $\tau$ contains the product topology.

But how do I know the other inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an open ball of radius $r$ around an element $x\in Z$ under the metric $d.$ For $r\leq 2,$ this is precisely a cylinderset, and for $r>2,$ this is $Z.$ Both of these are open under the product topology. Since every open ball under the metric topology is open under the product topology, the product topology also contains the metric topology.